# Reload movie recommendation dataset in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and was playing around with the movie recommendation graph in the sandbox when I accidentally deleted all the entries. I tried creating a new project, but the movie dataset is missing from the list. Can someone please tell me how to restore it? I searched for this in the Neo4j community, but could not find anything to help me out.

Comment: create one more sandbox with different account simple.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
:play movie-graph
```

This link has information about several sample data sets you can work with, including movies, Northwind store, and Game of Thrones.

https://neo4j.com/developer/example-data/

Comment: I tried this, but this is a smaller subset of the movie dataset and does not contain what is present in the original movielens dataset.